# How to clean up a failed pip installed app?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I was trying to install `flask` onto a Raspberry Pi Raspbian using `pip-3.2 install flask`. However, the installation failed. I tried to uninstall using `pip-3.2 uninstall flask`.  It said "Successfully uninstalled Flask", but `flask` appears to be still around. `import flask` doesn't complain about a missing module but instead reports on a syntax error in `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py`.

The following folders are still in `/usr/lib/python3.2/dist-packages`:

```
drwxr-sr-x  5 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:12 flask
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:12 Flask-0.10.1-py3.2.egg-info
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 itsdangerous-0.24-py3.2.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  31840 Nov 14 02:12 itsdangerous.py
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 jinja2
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 Jinja2-2.8-py3.2.egg-info
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 markupsafe
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 MarkupSafe-0.23-py3.2.egg-info
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff 518723 Aug 14 16:01 setuptools-1.4-py3.2.egg
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff     27 Aug 14 16:01 setuptools.pth
drwxr-sr-x  5 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 werkzeug
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff   4096 Nov 14 02:13 Werkzeug-0.11.2-py3.2.egg-info
```

How do I clean up and start all over again?